# Spring overloaded constructor injection

Tags: java, spring, constructor-injection

This is the code :

```
public class Triangle {


private String color;
private int height;


public Triangle(String color,int height){
    this.color = color;
    this.height = height;
}

public Triangle(int height ,String color){
    this.color = color;
    this.height = height;
}

public void draw() {
    System.out.println("Triangle is drawn , +
            "color:"+color+" ,height:"+height);
}

}
```

The Spring config-file is :

```
 <bean id="triangle" class="org.tester.Triangle">
    <constructor-arg value="20" />
    <constructor-arg value="10" />
</bean>
```

Is there any specific rule to determine which constructor will be called by Spring ?

Comment: FYI - I am deleting my answer.  I misread the spring docs at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-constructor-injection.  For me it seems to select the first constructor in the class, but I don't think it's guaranteed and others may get different results.

Comment: My WAG would be the order it which Java returns the constructors when using reflection.  I imagine it uses the first one to fix.  If you want to know the real answer, look up the source.

Comment: see [Spring constructor argument ambiguity](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31728258/217324)

Answer (score 5):

Here, the first argument will be matched to the first parameter of each method and then the parameter will be matched.

I would suggest the solution below to help remove ambiguity

If you want to call your first constructor use

```
<bean id="triangle" class="org.tester.Triangle">
<constructor-arg type="int"  value="20" />
<constructor-arg type="java.lang.String"  value="10" />
</bean>
```

If you want to call your second constructor use

```
<bean id="triangle" class="org.tester.Triangle">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String"value="20" />
    <constructor-arg   type="int"  value="10" />
</bean>
```

So that resolves the ambiguity

**EDIT :-**

Please read more about this problem [here](http://www.theserverside.com/tutorial/Solving-the-Constructor-Ambiguity-Problem-with-Spring-3-Annotations).

Comment: Both constructors have two parameters. I intend to know which one will spring prefer if we don't mention type ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so. Note that you can type the arguments e.g:

```
<bean id="triangle" class="org.tester.Triangle">
    <constructor-arg type="int" value="20" />
    <constructor-arg value="10" />
</bean>
```

which would remove the confusion in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't intend to resolve the ambiguity . I intend to know what Spring does to resolve this case .

Answer (score 0):

Based on tests for Spring 3.1.0, the second constructor will be used. I don't know why, the documentation didn't give any definitive answer.

[Bitbucket code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864787/spring-overloaded-constructor-injection) To test, run Main class, it will output String FIRST or SECOND, depending which constructor will be used to create Triangle object.