# What is the logic in spring to choose constructor when ambiguity constructors prasents

Tags: spring

First i need to tell **I know how to solve this problem using type and index in Spring config file. but i want to learn how spring chose constructor when ambiguity constructors are presents**.

Pojo Class

```
package a.b.c;

public class Square {

    private String color;
    private int sideLength;

    public Square(String color, int sideLength) {
        System.out.println("Constructor id #1");
        this.sideLength = sideLength;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Square(int sideLength, String color) {
        System.out.println("Constructor id #2");
        this.sideLength = sideLength;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Square(Integer sideLength, String color) {
        System.out.println("Constructor id #3");
        this.sideLength = sideLength;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("square color : " + color + ", sideLenth : " + sideLength);
    }

}
```

ApplicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="square" class="a.b.c.Square">
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="red" />
        <constructor-arg type="int" value="10" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

calling class

```
package a.b.c;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ApplicationContext.xml");

        Square square = (Square) context.getBean("square");
        square.draw();

    }

}
```

with this arrangement it **pick number #2 Constructor**.

without any config change if swap constructor position in source file as below

```
package a.b.c;

public class Square {

    private String color;
    private int sideLength;

    public Square(int sideLength, String color) {
        System.out.println("Constructor id #2");
        this.sideLength = sideLength;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Square(String color, int sideLength) {
        System.out.println("Constructor id #1");
        this.sideLength = sideLength;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Square(Integer sideLength, String color) {
        System.out.println("Constructor id #3");
        this.sideLength = sideLength;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("square color : " + color + ", sideLenth : " + sideLength);
    }

}
```

Nothing changed except method positions. **now it pick #1 constructor**.

My question is what is the logic to pick constructor when ambiguity comes.

Note: I know this can resolve using index.

Comment: Did you go through the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-ctor-arguments-resolution)?

Comment: @ Sotirios Delimanolis thanks for this link. Yes i did went through those as well as plenty of blog and technical articles before post this. all those says how to resolve this. but non of those say how it chosen. i mean how selected constructor change when its position changed in source.

Comment: you mean when it swap method in source file executing constructor getting change?

Comment: Yes it is. it always chosen middle one out of 3

Comment: can anyone point out me to source file in github. so i would be able to understand..

Comment: @NathanHughes Thanks for your direction. but there you says "it depends which it finds first." i think that CANT be. there has to be a logic right? because i always sees what choose it FIXED unless you change the position of method with in source. what i am looking is that logic. is it last constructor? or first constructor? that is what i am looking for.

Comment: @NathanHughes Agreed with you. Suddenly I have experience this use case. that is why i wanted to know the story behind it. your and Krishantha's answers made it clear to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring overloaded constructor injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864787/spring-overloaded-constructor-injection)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for how it selected in code level. but i am not sure why you worry about it. but personally appreciate your effort to get that instead of randomly believe. 
I am not sure that i can give exact answer you looking for. but i will guide you. spring source is in github. so you can check your self.

when it has un guided (using index) multiple constructors spring confused what to choose. it cannot be random. as you said it has to have logic. this is how its work.

spring has class call ConstructorResolver. when spring needs to resolve constructor it goes there. in your case 3 constructors are eligible. all are in same equal qualification. since all are unguided it goes to autowire mode to resolve candidate constructor.

so what it do is it first sorting the all 3 constructors using java.util.comparator. after that its trying to parse your all 3 connectors. (createArgumentArray) but Integer constructor would generate exception based on values you given. that goes out and 2 only remains.
then it calculate type difference weight to choose the method. ( i don't think i should explain that logic also here) it try type difference weight on both the converted arguments and the raw arguments. If the raw weight is better the that will be candidate.

I hope i have given expected answer. you can go ahead from here. if anything is still unclear comment bellow.

EDIT: sortConstructors consider preferring public constructors and ones with a maximum number of arguments. The result will contain public constructors first with decreasing number of arguments, then non-public constructors, again with decreasing number of arguments. but in above case sort will not take effect. that is the reason to change executed method when source change.

Comment: Yes.. this is what i looked for. well explained.

Answer (score 0):

Spring uses these three factors to chose the constructor

1. Matching the quantities or the number of arguments.
2. Matching the type.
3. Matching the order.

You can see this article that explains the ambiguity and how to solve it.

http://www.bullraider.com/java/spring3/tutorials/spring-ioc-tutorials/resolving-ambiguity

Comment: I already went through this article. in my case number of arguments fixed. first it chosen (int sideLength, String color) constructor and then its chosen (String color, int sideLength) constructor. only change i did is change the position of that method in source file.