# spring constructor overloading dependancy injection

Tags: spring

My pojo class to inject dependancies
    private int id;
    private int age;
    private String name;

```
Pojo(int id){
    this.id=id;
}
Pojo(int age, String name){
    this.age=age;
    this.name=name;
}
public void getDetails(){
    System.out.println("id= "+ id +"age= "+age+"name= "+name);
}
```

configuration.xml

```
    <constructor-arg value="1390" type="int" />
    <constructor-arg value="25" type="int" index="0" />
    <constructor-arg value="Ravi" type="String" index="1"/>
```

Exception: Error creating bean with name 'id1' defined in class path resource [conf.xml]: Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)

Comment: Spring will use single constructor to create an object. You need a constructor definition which will match parameter count and parameter types

Answer (score 1):

Add this constructor and try

```
Pojo(int id, int age, String name){
    this.id=id
    this.age=age;
    this.name=name;
}
```

Also modify your configuration.xml

```
 <constructor-arg value="1390" type="int" index="0"/>
 <constructor-arg value="25" type="int" index="1" />
 <constructor-arg value="Ravi" type="String" index="2"/>
```

Reason for Error: 
You are passing three parameters in the configuration.xml, and there is no equivalent constructor in your code to receive three parameters.

Comment: So, those overloading constructors are not possible ?

Comment: No. Spring can only call one constructor to create an object, not two.

Comment: Constructor overloading is possible, we can have it in the code, but spring can invoke only one constructor to create an object, which constructor we need to invoke, we have to give it in the configuration.xml. More info on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864787/spring-overloaded-constructor-injection